# Strange MethodMissingException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, missingmethodexception

I have stumbled upon interesting problem which is destroying me last couple of hours. I have project in VS, in references I have library Communication.dll, which contains class Service.
I am invoking following method:

```
public void ConnectPipe()
{
    Service service = new Service();
    service.ConnectionMode = ConnectionModes.PIPE;
    service.Connect();
}
```

when I run it, on second line I get `MissingMethodException - Method not found: 'Void Service.set_ConnectionMode()'`
when I press F12 on service class, I get the Assembly info for the class. When I look for my property, setter is in place, so it does not look like problem with referenced library:

```
public ConnectionModes ConnectionMode { get; set; }
```

has anyone any idea where problem might be please?

Comment: Try rebuild solution.It should help

Comment: I have cleaned it, built it and re-built it so many times I cannot count it:)

Comment: Try delete reference to Communication.dll and then add it

Comment: Thx, but I have also tried it, even removing the "using" directive from class and adding it after I have added the reference again

Comment: still do not know where the problem is(the other one than the one between chair and keyboard), even decompiler shows that the setter is in my library... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue. Fixed by updating reference to the library.

Point to the exact file on the local, through button "Browse..." don't choose from the library list in references manager - that doesn't work correctly sometimes.

And rebuild the referenced assembly.

Comment: yep, referenced assembly was the problem back then